# Angular 4 NG Build --Prod error with dialogs

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm getting the following errors while trying to run NG Build --Prod (for AoT compiling of course)

```
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/DTurcich/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/add.notification.one.dialog.component.html (7,96): Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.

ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/DTurcich/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/add.notification.one.dialog.component.html (7,138): Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.

ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/DTurcich/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/add.notification.one.dialog.component.html (13,47): Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.

ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/DTurcich/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/add.notification.one.dialog.component.html (7,4): Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.

ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/DTurcich/DashboardConsole/ASCI.DashboardConsole.Frontend/src/app/add.notification.one.dialog.component.html (6,3): Property 'newAdmin' does not exist on type 'AddNotificationOneDialog'.
```

These errors are only being thrown when attempting to do NG Build --Prod.  non --Prod builds are being completed successfully, I know that AoT compiling does things differently but I'm unsure what I need to do to remedy the situation because what I have looked up hasn't seemed to help.

**Pertinent Files:**

Angular 4 Typescript:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'add-notification-one-dialog',
    templateUrl: './add.notification.one.dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class AddNotificationOneDialog {
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<AddNotificationOneDialog>,
        private snackBar: MdSnackBar

    ) { }

    // opens a dialog to warn the user they didn't input correctly
    openSnackBar(message) {
        this.snackBar.open(message, "Close", { duration: 3000 });
    }

    // function called on press of the submit button which checks regular expression compliance 
    pressSubmit(newAdmin: any): void {
        var regEx = new RegExp("[^a-zA-z0-9]");
        var testedInput = regEx.test(newAdmin);

        if (testedInput !== true) {
            this.dialogRef.close(newAdmin)
        }
        else {
            this.openSnackBar("Please enter only A-Z and 0-9");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dialog-box">
    <h1 md-dialog-title>Add a new Administrator?</h1>

    <md-dialog-content>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput class="text-input" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]+" placeholder="Name" maxlength="30" [(ngModel)]="newAdmin" [value]="newAdmin" (keyup.enter)="pressSubmit(newAdmin)">
        </md-input-container>
    </md-dialog-content>

    <md-dialog-actions>
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="pull-left" md-raised-button (click)="pressSubmit(newAdmin)">Submit</button>
            <button class="pull-right" md-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You did not copy the right file. Please give us add.field.dialog.component.html.

Comment: I edited it, i meant to put the above errors, they're all related so i just chose one section of the given errors.

Comment: I know what the error is and how to fix it. Please give us the add.field.dialog.component.html. Otherwise I can't fix it. It's a simple AOT error. You are calling a function with an argument `myFunction(myVar)` but the declaration of the function does not have any argument `void myFunction()` or vice-versa. Therefore the AOT compilation will break and throw an error.

Comment: I updated the errors, but all the dialogs are throwing errors and are all structured the same.

Comment: I posted an answer. Don't forget to accept it if it fixes the error. In order to prevent such errors, the Visual Studio Code IDE has an Angular Language Service extension built by the Angular team that throws AOT Diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare your newAdmin variable:

```
export class AddNotificationOneDialog {

  public newAdmin: any;

  constructor(...){ }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yup, that was the error. I didn't realize that was necessary seeing as just setting the type in the constructor was working for a normal build.